# Why do I need to implement Apply in Java Guava function?

Tags: java, guava

For example, following is the standard pattern

```
Function<Integer, Integer> powerOfTwo = new Function<Integer, Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer apply(Integer input) {
        return (int) Math.pow(input, 2);
    }
};
```

What is the advantage of implementing apply? Wouldn't it be cleaner to write

```
Function<Integer, Integer> powerOfTwo = new Function<Integer, Integer>(Integer input) {
    return (int) Math.pow(input, 2);
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, of course, but this is how the Java language worked, at least until lambdas were introduced in Java 8.  This has nothing to do with Guava and everything to do with the Java language.

As of Java 8, you could just write

```
Function<Integer, Integer> powerOfTwo = input -> (int) Math.pow(input, 2);
```

...but if you're not on Java 8, then the way the language is designed makes it so you have to write the first version.

Comment: See [FunctionalExplained · google/guava Wiki](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/FunctionalExplained) for more details.

Comment: I'm not sure that actually answers any of the OP's questions, which just seem to be about the syntax of anonymous inner classes.

Comment: I'm new to Java, so sorry if this is very basic. Why do I even need an function interface is there is only one method? Why not just write a normal method instead of a function? When you say this is how Java works, is there any specific design decision / paradigm that made it this way?

Comment: Because you can't pass around methods.  You can only pass around objects.  So you need an object to carry your method for you.